# how to paginate when condition is correct laravel 5

Tags: sql, database, laravel, pagination

i have few simple code and i wanna paginate when my condition is correct

here my codes

Route:

```
Route::resource('lang','zabanController');
```

Controller :

```
public function index(){
$show=DB::table('zaban')->paginate(5);
return view('twoLang.index',compact('show'));
}

public function show($id)
{

    DB::table('zaban')->where('default_lang','!=',$id)->update([
        'default_lang'=>$id
    ]);
 }
```

View :

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
    <div>
        <a href="{{action('zabanController@show',1)}}">Per</a>
        <a href="{{action('zabanController@show',0)}}">ENG</a>
    </div>
            <table class="table table-hover table-bordered table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>id</th>
                        <th>lang ID</th>
                        <th>Default lang</th>
                        <th>Content</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                @foreach($show as $content)
                    @if($content->my_lang==$content->default_lang)
                        <tr>
                            <th>{{$content->id}}</th>
                            <th>{{$content->my_lang}}</th>
                            <th>{{$content->default_lang}}</th>
                            <th>{{$content->content}}</th>
                        </tr>
                    @endif
                @endforeach
                </tbody>
            </table>
            {{$show->links()}}

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

DB -> Table Name 'zaban'

table Fields => id , my_lang , default_lang ,created_at , updated_at

and here my problem

i wanna paginate content that 'my_lang' = 'default_lang'

just like this

id = 1  , my_lang = 0 , default_lang = 1

id = 2  , my_lang = 1 , default_lang = 1

id = 3  , my_lang = 0 , default_lang = 1

ok.here just need return id=2

ofcourse default_lang may change in process but my_lang always is fix (if i wrote correct :) )

meaning if table field change like this :

id = 1  , my_lang = 0 , default_lang = 0

id = 2  , my_lang = 1 , default_lang = 1

id = 3  , my_lang = 0 , default_lang = 0

need to return id=1 and id=3

hope clear my mind

i wrote this in my controller but no chance

```
$show=DB::table('zaban')->where('my_lang','default_lang')->paginate(5);
```

and this

```
 $alls=DB::table('zaban')->get();
 foreach($alls as $al)
{
$show = DB::table('zaban')->where('my_lang','default_lang')->paginate(5);
}
```

Comment: i got an array without any data   //    here output : Collection {#297 ▼
  #items: []
}

Comment: i got error : ErrorException in Builder.php line 775:
                    Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your query you search **string** '*default_lang*' in '*my_lang*' **column** that is why you get an empty collection.
You can `orderBy` *default_lang*:

```
$show=DB::table('zaban')->orderBy('default_lang')->paginate(5);
```

Or select '*default_lang*' where value is 'some value ...':

```
$show=DB::table('zaban')->where('default_lang','some value ...')->paginate(5);
```

If you want verify that two columns are equal:

```
$show = DB::table('zaban')
                ->whereColumn('my_lang', 'default_lang')
                ->paginate(5);
```

Comment: did not work and they not String !!  here my migration :    $table->enum('my_lang',(['0','1']));    $table->enum('default_lang',(['0','1']));

Comment: You want to select data where 'my_lang' = 'default_lang' ? And what your Laravel version?

Comment: yes i wanna do that and my laravel version is 5.4.13